# Update MySQL row with "values" statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

The thing is that i have some dynamic columns and i use always the same php ajax page. So i get from the other page some coma separated strings. One with the columns, other with the table and other with the data. In the insert there is no problem because i do it this way:

```
$query =  'INSERT INTO '.$_GET["table"].' ('.$_GET["columns"].') VALUES('.$_GET["data"].')';
mysql_query($query, $link);
```

That transforms to this:

```
INSERT sys_users_cfg (usr,pwd,permission_id,image) VALUES ('pepwe2','1234','1','')
```

I need to do the UPDATE in the same way. with VALUES statement. Like:

```
UPDATE sys_users_cfg (usr,pwd,permission_id,image) VALUES ('pepwe2','1234','1','') WHERE usr_id = 33
```

That dosnt work. Is this posible?

Comment: `UPDATE ... SET \`column\`=value'`,\`column2\`='value' ..

Comment: @GeoPhoenix you beat me too it.

Comment: Im asking if i can use "values" statement. I know how to update in the other way but because of the way that i recive the variables the "values" statement fits better.

Comment: you can't `update` using `values`. `update` statement has a specific syntax. look at my answer, the `explode` separates out `$_GET` to fit the `update` query.

Comment: REPLACE INTO worked for me. Your solution is ok too but its more simple with REPLACE INTO and works too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the REPLACE INTO syntax instead if you're updating using the primary key, e.g.

`REPLACE INTO sys_users_cfg (usr_id,usr,pwd,permission_id,image) VALUES (33,'pepwe2','1234','1','')`.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL update is in a different format, see http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlupdate.php

```
UPDATE table SET column = 'value', column2 = 'value2' WHERE id = ID
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you update a row :

```
UPDATE sys_users_cfg SET usr = 'pepwe2', pwd = '1234', permission_id = 1, image = '' WHERE usr_id = 33
```

You can go read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html for more information.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $values = explode(',', $_GET['data']);
 $query = "UPDATE sys_users_cfg SET usr = '$values[0]', pwd = '$values[1]', permission_id = '$values[2]', image = '' WHERE usr_id = '33'";
```